# Python Pillow - Draw text on a frame with font color

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How do I specify the color of the text when using `Pillow` to draw text over a frame?

What I tried so far is as shown below, it writes the text, but the color of the text is not `blue`.

```
# Draw the text on the frame
d = ImageDraw.Draw(frame)
d.text((150, 10), str(balance_total), 'blue', font)
```

Comment: try add "fill=" in front of the color value

Comment: as bing wang said, `fill="blue"` should do the trick.